# Input contacts and taking it to the home screen

Tags: java, android

I am accepting 3 contacts from the user and then moving to the home screen as a part of registration process. But when some parts of the details are not filled, I need it to be checked and give a toast or prompt to fill all the details. Then the user can return back to filling the rest of the details--the blank spaces. When the details are filled the user clicks register button and app shifts to home screen.

Kindly help to find what is wrong with the current code. I am a complete beginner. Any help is appreciated.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AddContacts extends AppCompatActivity {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

  Button registerbtn;
  EditText name1, num1, name2, num2, name3, num3;
  String emname1,emname2,emname3;
  int emnum1,emnum2,emnum3;

  @Override

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addcontacts);


    sharedPreferences =  this.getSharedPreferences("universe.sk.syndriveapp.addcontacts", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    registerbtn= findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);

    name1 = findViewById(R.id.name1);
    num1 = findViewById(R.id.num1);

    name2 = findViewById(R.id.name2);
    num2 = findViewById(R.id.num2);

    name3 = findViewById(R.id.name3);
    num3 = findViewById(R.id.num3);

    registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            emname1 = name1.getText().toString();
            emnum1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
            emname2 = name2.getText().toString();
            emnum2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
            emname3 = name3.getText().toString();
            emnum3 = Integer.parseInt(num3.getText().toString());

            if (emname1.isEmpty() || emname2.isEmpty() || emname3.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this,"Please fill all details!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {

                editor.putString("name1", emname1);
                editor.putInt("num1", emnum1);
                editor.putString("name2", emname2);
                editor.putInt("num2", emnum2);
                editor.putString("name3", emname3);
                editor.putInt("num3", emnum3);

                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this,"Registration Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(AddContacts.this,NavigationActivity.class));
            }


                        }});


         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onClick(view);` after you show the `Toast`  
`onClick(view);` should be triggered only if the user clicks the button and

Surround all your parsers with a try/catch block:

```
try {
    emnum1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    enum1 = -1
}
```

you can change -1 to what you want if the TextView does not contain a valid number

Comment: yes did that...but when the user clicks register after only some of the details are filled the app crashes.